# Enable a llvm pass for Os but not O2

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I have a pass running on O2 and now want to disable it on Os. One solution is to add a compilation option like the following:

```c
 static cl::opt<bool> DisableMyPass("disable-mypass",cl::Hidden,cl::init(false));
```

and use it with `-mllvm disable-mypass=true`.
But what I exactly need is by default disabling it when -Os while enabling it when -O2 without any other command line options, and I cannot find out a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
// This pass generally increases code size
if (skipFunction(F) || F.optForSize()) {
  return false;
}
```

at start of `runOnFunction`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that function.